# How to get duplicated item substrings from a list? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach, items

lets say I have a list with items :

```
TEST1 -- 99,56$ -- 25 PCS  -- 10:56
TEST2 -- 56,57$ -- 57 PCS  -- 11:01
TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06
TEST4 -- 56,57$ -- 59 PCS  -- 11:33
TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06
TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06
TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 11:45
```

And I would want to get only duplicated items where the NAME Value (NAME Value is the first part where TEST is) and PCS Value is the same, into a new list, so my desired new list output would be:

```
TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06
TEST1 -- 99,56$ -- 25 PCS  -- 10:56
TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 11:45
```

MY CURRENT CODE:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

   

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> listwithbuys = new List<string>(new string[] { 
"TEST1 -- 99,56$ -- 25 PCS  -- 10:56",
"TEST2 -- 56,57$ -- 57 PCS  -- 11:01",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST4 -- 56,57$ -- 59 PCS  -- 11:33",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 11:45" });
             List<String> duplicates = listwithbuys.GroupBy(x => x)
                             .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                             .Select(g => g.Key)
                             .ToList();
           listbox1.DataSource = duplicates;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code would print me:

```
TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06
```

Which is not my goal, like I said I only want it to give me duplicated items where NAME and PCS Value are the same. Thanks to anyone trying to help :)

Comment: Which column is the Name?

Comment: The first part, where TEST is

Comment: It seems, that you should split your string

Comment: @HassanBrate You have done the grouping on the whole string. That's why `TEST3` is the only duplicate. The exact same line appears 3times in your source list.

Comment: How can I do the grouping for 2 specified parts of the string, any idea ?

Comment: In your desired output, why TEST3 is not included which has the same PCS value?

Comment: yeah you are rigth @MukeshVadodariya, going to correct, I forgot

Comment: @HassanBrate, did you try my code? let me know if it is giving the expected output OR not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this code, let me know if have any queries.

```
List<string> listwithbuys = new List<string>(new string[] {
"TEST1 -- 99,56$ -- 25 PCS  -- 10:56",
"TEST2 -- 56,57$ -- 57 PCS  -- 11:01",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST4 -- 56,57$ -- 59 PCS  -- 11:33",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST3 -- 56,57$ -- 43 PCS  -- 11:06",
"TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 11:45" });
            List<String> duplicates = listwithbuys.GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Split(new string[] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0], 
                                                                     PCS = x.Split(new string[] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2] })
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .Select(g => g.LastOrDefault())
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: cant be compiled says:  ` Name = x.Split(" -- ")[0], PCS = x.Split(" -- ")[2] } `               " Eror :   conversion from string to char not possible"  @MukeshVadodariya

Comment: I have tested it with .Net core 3.1 here is demo sample. https://dotnetfiddle.net/y971YP

Comment: I am using NET 4.5 maybe thats why :( @MukeshVadodariya

Comment: @HassanBrate, Converted .net core to .Net 4.5, try it now. here is demo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/axuR5N

Comment: I love you buddy <3 thanks so much @MukeshVadodariya, may I contact you for another similiar question ?

Comment: @HassanBrate, sure dear! please my answer if it fits with your expectation.

Comment: Yes buddy one question left : how can I make it output the most recent  duplicate so desired output would be : "TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 11:45" and not "TEST1 -- 58,98$ -- 25 PCS  -- 10:56" ? @MukeshVadodariya

Comment: @HassanBrate Edited my answer, can you try it now.